# Is Uno.UI.WpfHost still supported for debugging Uno wasm projects?

Tags: uno-platform

I followed the instructions [here](https://platform.uno/docs/articles/uno-development/working-with-uno-wpf-host.html) for setting up a wpf host, but the app starts without ever loading my code. I also tried to get WASM debugging to work with no success. That said, I'd rather have a wpf host if possible since I think that will have a faster/smoother debugging and development experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `Uno.UI.WpfHost` is [no longer maintained](https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/issues/2000).

There's currently no one perfect solution for debugging on Uno-WebAssembly; the debugger is temperamental, as you've noticed, and limited even when it does work. One option is to [add a Skia head](https://platform.uno/docs/articles/get-started-dotnet-new.html) to your project (Linux and/or WPF), for which the debugging experience is very good and the comportment of Uno is close to that on WebAssembly.